# How to group nodes between nodes?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

I know that this has been answered before, but I am curious about how to achieve this without keys.

I have this XML and I have to get the nodes between {%tab%} and {%endtab%}.

```
<element>
  <hello>{%tab%}</hello>
  <hello>yes</hello>
  <hello>{%endtab%}</hello>
  <hello>no</hello>
  <hello>no</hello>
  <hello>{%tab%}</hello>
  <hello>yes</hello>
  <hello>{%endtab%}</hello>
</element>
```

This is what I got:

```
  <xsl:template match="hello[preceding-sibling::hello[not(normalize-space(text())!='{%tab%}')]]
                     [following-sibling::hello[not(normalize-space(text())!='{%endtab%}')]]
                     [
                     (preceding-sibling::hello[not(normalize-space(text())!='{%tab%}')])[1]/(following-sibling::hello[not(normalize-space(text())!='{%endtab%}')])[1]
                     = (following-sibling::hello[not(normalize-space(text())!='{%endtab%}')])[1]
                     ]">
    <strong><xsl:value-of select="." /></strong>
  </xsl:template>
```

This selects all nodes that are followed by {%endtab%} and are preceded by {%tab%} nodes.

```
hello[preceding-sibling::hello[not(normalize-space(text())!='{%tab%}')]]
                         [following-sibling::hello[not(normalize-space(text())!='{%endtab%}')]]
```

The problem with this is that the "no" nodes are also selected because they are also between those nodes. So, I have to ensure that the  {%endtab%} that follows certain node (its first occurrence) is the same that the one that follows the preceding {%tab%}, which I do with this XPath:

```
[
(preceding-sibling::hello[not(normalize-space(text())!='{%tab%}')])[1]
/(following-sibling::hello[not(normalize-space(text())!='{%endtab%}')])[1]
= (following-sibling::hello[not(normalize-space(text())!='{%endtab%}')])[1]
]
```

But, this is not filtering the "no" nodes as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This XPath expression**:

```
 /*/*[not(. = '{%tab%}' or . = '{%endtab%}') 
    and preceding-sibling::*[. = '{%tab%}' or . = '{%endtab%}'][1] = '{%tab%}'
    and following-sibling::*[. = '{%tab%}' or . = '{%endtab%}'][1] = '{%endtab%}'
     ]
```

selects any element that is a child of the top element and is between a sibling element with string-value `{%tab%}` and a sibling element with string-value `{%endtab%}`

**Here is a running proof with a simple XSLT transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:copy-of select=
    "/*/*[not(. = '{%tab%}' or . = '{%endtab%}') 
        and preceding-sibling::*[. = '{%tab%}' or . = '{%endtab%}'][1] = '{%tab%}'
        and following-sibling::*[. = '{%tab%}' or . = '{%endtab%}'][1] = '{%endtab%}'
         ]"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided source XML document**:

```
<element>
  <hello>{%tab%}</hello>
  <hello>yes</hello>
  <hello>{%endtab%}</hello>
  <hello>no</hello>
  <hello>no</hello>
  <hello>{%tab%}</hello>
  <hello>yes</hello>
  <hello>{%endtab%}</hello>
</element>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<hello>yes</hello>
<hello>yes</hello>
```

Answer (score 3):

Ignore the following siblings and count the preceding `tab`s and the preceding `endtab`s.  If they aren't equal, you are are either an `endtab` or a `yes`.  Exclude the case where you're an `endtab`.

Allow me to dispense with `normalize-space()` to make the example clearer.

```
<xsl:template match="hello[
    (. != '{%endtab%}')
    and
    (
        count(preceding-sibling::hello[. = '{%tab%}'])
        != count(preceding-sibling::hello[. = '{%endtab%}'])
    )
    ]">
```

Answer (score 2):

Two notes of general interest:

### 1.

> I know that this has been answered before, but I am curious about how
>   to achieve this without keys.

A link to the solution using a **key** would be in order:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/28179346/3016153

### 2.

Since an XSLT 2.0 solution has been suggested earlier, I would suggest another one which I believe is much simpler:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/element">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="hello" group-starting-with="hello[.='{%tab%}']">
            <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-ending-with="hello[.='{%endtab%}']">
                <xsl:if test="current-group()[self::hello[.='{%tab%}']]">
                    <xsl:for-each select="current-group()[not(position()=1 or position()=last())]">
                        <strong><xsl:value-of select="." /></strong>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** at first I didn't notice the [xslt-1.0](/questions/tagged/xslt-1.0) tag; this answer is probably useless for the original poster

Using **XSLT 2.0** and the same clever trick of [@bjimba's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29056074/how-to-group-nodes-between-nodes#answer-29056369) you could group together the elements inside a "tab", which would allow to do something both with the whole group and with each single `hello` element:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
    ...
    <xsl:for-each-group select="hello" group-by="my:tabId(.)">
        <!-- do something with a whole run -->
        <strong>
            <!-- do something with the single elements -->
            <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
        </strong>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
    ...

<xsl:function name="my:tabId" as="xs:integer?">
    <xsl:param name="e" as="element()"/>
    <xsl:variable name="tabStartCount" 
        select="count($e/preceding-sibling::hello[. = '{%tab%}'])"/>
    <xsl:variable name="tabEndCount" 
        select="count($e/preceding-sibling::hello[. = '{%endtab%}'])"/>
    <xsl:sequence select="
        if ($e != '{%endtab%}' and ($tabStartCount > $tabEndCount)) then
            $tabStartCount
        else
            ()
    "/>
</xsl:function>
```

Comment: This question is tagged `xslt-1.0`.

Comment: @michael.hor257k: you are right, sorry, I didn't notice that tag until you pointed it out; note added, do you think it would be better to delete the answer altogether?

Comment: I don't really care. I just thought it was important to make it clear.